# Putting list length to QLabel in PyQt4

Tags: python, arrays, pyqt4

I have made Multi-Page Quiz application in PyQt4, I'm trying to add score summary at the end, so it will count how many correct and incorrect answers were there.

For that I have made lists, this is how I made it:

```
def scorecheck(self, sendercheck): # sendercheck object gets from which widget was signal sent.
    wronganswers = [] 
    correctanswers = []
    if sendercheck == ( self.answ or self.answ1 ):
        wronganswers.append(1)


    if sendercheck == ( self.answ2 ):
        correctanswers.append(1)
```

---

How can I put `wronganswers` length in QLabel?

**I have tried these:**

```
self.wronganswerlabel = QtGui.QLabel(self)
self.wronganswerlabel.setText(len(wronganswers))
self.wronganswerlabel.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)
self.wronganswerlabel.show()
```

Gave me this error:

> self.wronganswer.setText(len(wronganswers))
>   TypeError: QLabel.setText(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'

**and this:**

```
self.wronganswerlabel = QtGui.QLabel(self, "Score:".len(wronganswers))
self.wronganswerlabel.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)
self.wronganswerlabel.show()
```

**Gave me error:**

> self.wronganswer = QtGui.QLabel(self, "Score:".len(wronganswers))
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'len'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a casting thing; [`QtGui.QLabel()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlabel.html#QLabel-2) and [`QtGui.QLabel.setText()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlabel.html#setText) expects a `QtCore.QString` or just a `unicode` or `string` object, but you are trying to pass an int.  You need to tell python how to translate the integer into a string.  The usual way is `str(myint)`

Additionally, you need to use the + operator to combine two strings -- the way you have the syntax now, you are asking the string `"Score:"` for it's length method, which is probably not what you meant.

The following should work as expected

```
self.wronganswerlabel.setText(str(len(wronganswers)))
```

OR

```
self.wronganswerlabel = QtGui.QLabel("Score:" + str(len(wronganswers)),  self)
```

Comment: Gave me this error @lemonhead    `File "quiz.py", line 352, in scorecheck
    self.wronganswerlabel = QtGui.QLabel(self, "Score:" + str(len(wronganswers)))
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QLabel(QWidget parent=None, Qt.WindowFlags flags=0): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'
  QLabel(QString, QWidget parent=None, Qt.WindowFlags flags=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Window'`

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer with explanation! i fixed the problem with putting self at the end:        `self.wronganswerlabel = QtGui.QLabel("Score:" + str(len(wronganswers)), self)
        self.wronganswerlabel.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)
        self.wronganswerlabel.show()`